# of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm using mvc 4 web api for getting `JSONArray` and consume it in android application but this error is occurred:

```
of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

this is JSON:

```
[{
"FileType": {
    "FileTypeId": 1,
    "Name": "Estate",
    "CodeLength": 5
},
"FileId": 2,
"FileTypeId": 1,
"FileNumber": "12345"
}, {
"FileType": {
    "FileTypeId": 1,
    "Name": "Estate",
    "CodeLength": 5
},
"FileId": 3,
"FileTypeId": 1,
"FileNumber": "12345"
}]
```

and this is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr); //<=== Error is Here

                JSONArray Files = null;

                // Getting JSON Array node
                Files = jArray;

                // looping through All Files
                for (int i = 0; i < Files.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Files.getJSONObject(i);

                    String FileNumber = c.getString(TAG_FileNumber);

                    // FileType node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject FileType = c.getJSONObject(TAG_FileType);
                    String Name = FileType.getString(TAG_FileType_Name);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> file = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    file.put(TAG_FileNumber, FileNumber);
                    file.put(TAG_FileType_Name, Name);

                    // adding file to file list
                    FileList.add(file);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is that jsonStr printing?

Comment: In your json,there is no name for JSON array.

Comment: I took your code and simplified it.  I am not getting any errors.  Is it possible that the JSON String is not what you think you are getting?

Comment: @GiruBhai : string format is a JSONArray format if copy string in http://json2csharp.com/ it is in correct format

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not the best person to help you due to lack of knowledge in the specific field you ask answer for BUT:

I looked it up here: [http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.String)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29)

and one of the constructors takes String as a parameter and it says:
**Parameters: source - A string that begins with [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket).**

Try to enter a string of that format!

Comment: string format is a JSONArray format if copy string in http://json2csharp.com/ it is in correct format

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines into your json strings as

```
{
  "array":
// your json 
}
```

and change this line

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

to

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray jArray= jObj.getJSONArray("array");
```

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem, it would just complicate the parsing. There is no need to name the array.